# Perl @$ syntax meaning

Tags: arrays, perl, scalar

I have adapted a code fragment for getting column names in DBI and it works fine:

```
$tableColumns = $databaseStatement->{NAME};

print $fileHandle $documentFormatter->{openTableRow};
foreach(@$tableColumns){
  print $fileHandle $documentFormatter->{openTableHeader};
  print $fileHandle $_;
  print $fileHandle $documentFormatter->{closeTableHeader};
}
print $fileHandle $documentFormatter->{closeTableRow};
```

However, I do not fully understand why in line 3 I need to use **@$** when I iterate over the headers returned by statement execution. Also why would the variable **$tableColumns** be a scalar rather than an array?

Hope you can clarify this because I'm rather confused :(

Thanks in advance,
Fabio

Comment: For more information about reference variables, see [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, `$databaseStatement->{NAME}` returns an array ref.

```
$tableColumns = $databaseStatement->{NAME};
```

If you were to `print $tableColumns` you'd see something like `ARRAY(0x18af700)`.

So it's storing an array ref, how do you access that array? You *dereference* it.

```
for my $entry ( @{ $tableColumns } ) { ... }
```

The `@$tableColumns` is just shorthand syntax for dereferencing.

---

So what's the rationale for all this?

Perl does not allow you to store lists inside an array or as a hash value; you can only store scalar values. This include *references*, which then allows you to, for example,  store references to an array or hash inside another array or hash.

```
my @simpsons = ('Homer', 'Marge', 'Bart', 'Lisa', 'Maggie');

my %characters = (
    simpsons => \@simpsons, # Create references to existing array
    flanders => ['Ned', 'Maude', 'Rod', 'Tod'], # Anonymous array-ref
);

$simpsons[2] = 'Bort'; # This will affect the entry in the hash

for my $character ( @{ $characters{simpsons} } ) {
    print $character . "\n";
}
```

Note that I can't use the shorthand `@$characters{simpsons}` here, but if if I do `my $simpsons = $characters{simpsons}` I can then iterate over `@$simpsons`.

Comment: Thank you! I am still not very familiar with Perl references but you pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You state that you have "adapted a code fragment for getting column names in DBI", but it is not immediately evident how you have gotten to that point from the DBI library.

Reading *perldoc DBI*, the closest I get to something to retrieve column names is:

```
"column_info"
  $sth = $dbh->column_info( $catalog, $schema, $table, $column );

  # then $sth->fetchall_arrayref or $sth->fetchall_hashref etc
```

The *$sth->fetchall_arrayref* would return an array reference.  An array reference in Perl 5 is a scalar and is denoted with the '$' sigil.  To iterate over the elements of that arrayref, you need to de-reference the arrayref.  You can do that with either:

```
foreach (@$tableColumns) { ...
```

or, more formally:

```
foreach (@{$tableColumns}) { ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I think I might adopt the syntax you show in the last example.